# What's the difference between these two differential mode EMI filters?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, differential, emc, emi-filtering

When I search for differential mode input EMI filters (for power supplies), I get two different filter types:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPXPiQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What's the difference between these two differential mode filters?
(The values are random in the schematics.)

Comment: The low-side filter seems to be damped by the \$R_1C_4\$ network. This is to avoid resonance and interaction with the downstream switching converter. As you know, the incremental resistance of a closed-loop-operated switching converter is negative and can potentially interact with the \$LC\$ network if not properly damped.

Comment: @VerbalKint thank you for the answer, but how about the C1 on high side filter? It's not used in low side filter. Do you have an opinion about it?

Comment: It will interact with the mains output impedance and provide additional filtering for differential mode. As shown [here](https://impulse.schaffner.com/en/engineers-guide-to-designing-emi-filter) it is often added to work with the leakage inductance of the common-mode choke and provides differential filtering.

Comment: C1 is ineffective in the top circuit because it connects directly across a voltage source.